# Most efficient wlan module for a bunch of rcars

Tags: wifi, wireless, power-consumption

I want to build up a rc car on my own which I can connect/steer via an app - either smartphone or computer. Not decided, yet. I also want to use multiple cars, each for a friend so let's say in the end I will likely use 3-5 but maybe also even 10.
What would be the most efficient wlan module for that? I think I will need a battery or at least I'm not aware of any other energy supply. At the moment I am using an [ESP WROOM 32 from NodeMCU](https://www.makershop.de/en/plattformen/nodemcu/esp32-board-stiftleisten/).
Is that promising or is there maybe another module more useful?

Comment: The wifi chip power usage is going to be trivial compared to the motor

Comment: so it doesn't really matter which I use?

Comment: Note that WiFi is not really known for low and consistent latency, especially in noisy and busy environments. You probably need to factor that in. Also, many of the modules (especially the ubiquitous ESP32) only run on the 2.4 GHz band which can be very busy and noisy even before your start (especially in urban environments), so if you add a two dozen devices (the cars and the “drivers”) constantly streaming data, even if low bandwidth, that could quickly degrade pretty badly. You probably need to take that into account in the way you design your control protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that advice! What else could I do instead of Wifi? Bluetooth?

Comment: Have you considered just a digital radio module on 868Mhz? There are also many smarter protocols, out of my mind I can name ANT, Shockburst... LoRa seems quite overkill.

Comment: I'm very fresh into this topic so I'm absolutely not aware of all the advantages and disadvantages. Every new term I hear here feels to me like "Yeah, cool, why not.. I want to know that stuff" :) I think what I finally need is something everyone needs: A stable, fast and easy to manage/operate signal. I guess I need some more basic knowledge, which topic is it I am looking at?